# Selecting a cell and changing the alpha of all cells in tableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a project that needs something I never imagined to have. The app for iOS is directed to iPad due to size. To that question, I made a small prototype to show one of the parties to detail better.

This is a tableView where the functions and actions will happen.

[image]

And this is the Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let data:[String] = ["Row 0","Row 1", "Row 2","Row 3","Row 4","Row 5","Row 6"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell

        cell.labelText.text = self.data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        cell!.alpha = 0.5
    }

}
```

**What the app to do exactly?**

Well, when a row is selected, the rows below it need to stay with the Alpha equal to 0.5.

Examples:

**I touched the row 3**

Action:

Row 1, Row 2 and Row 3 will keep the **Alpha** equal to **1.0**

Row 4, Row 5 and Row 6 will keep the **Alpha** equal to **0.5**

**I touched in row 4**

Action:

Row 1, Row 2, Row 3 and Row 4 will keep the **Alpha** equal to **1.0**

Row 5, Row 6 will keep the **Alpha** equal to **0.5**

.

.

.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to set the alpha value in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, then simply reload that row when its tapped. This should preserve the alpha for that cell and set alpha to 1 on every other cell, even if the the user scrolls the cell offscreen.

```
var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    if let selectedIndexPath =  self.selectedIndexPath where indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row {
        cell.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
        cell.alpha = 1
    }

    cell.labelText.text = self.data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: Does this code work in swift-2? I test it but failed at `cell:Cell` with error: `use of undeclared type 'Cell'`

Comment: I copied it from the example code given. You'd want to cast it as a UITableViewCell not Cell. Answer updated.

Comment: Oh, seems I hijack it, I am not the owner.

Comment: My bad, assumed you were the owner :-P thanks for noticing the mistake though.

Comment: @Chris This seems to solve my problem, but still not all right. Whenever I select a cell, the table recharging eliminates the selection, then it is not applied the alpha 0.5. How can I fix this?

Comment: recharging = refreshing or scrolling?

Comment: @James then you may need to just hold your own reference to the selected index path. This way it won't be cleared out. Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Make an integer variable "`selectedCell"`, and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, set it equal to `indexPath.row`, then `tableView.reloadData()`

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simply use an if statement to determine if `indexPath.row` is greater than "`selectedCell`". If so then set the alpha value to `0.5`, otherwise set it to `1.0`.

It is generally a good practice to change cell properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because every time it is called you risk overwriting changes you make to cells elsewhere in the code. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am proposing below solution, please consider

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let data:[String] = ["Row 0","Row 1", "Row 2","Row 3","Row 4","Row 5","Row 6"]
    var rowSelected:Int
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell

        cell.labelText.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
        if rowSelected <= indexPath.row
cell!.alpha = 0.5;
else
cell!.alpha = 1.0;
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
rowSelected = indexPath.row

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are describing what you want it to do or the anormal behaviour.

There are two possibilities:

1) If you want the selection related alpha to render on a single row, you may want to override didDeselectRowAtIndexPath and set the alpha to 1.0 there.

2) You need to explicitly set the alpha after getting the cell from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier because you are not guaranteed to get a fresh cell instance every time.

The tableview will call cellForRowAtIndexPath for a variety of reasons even after showing it for the first time.  What is probably happening is that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for rows that have been deselected and  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier may or may not reuse an existing cell object.   When it reuses a cell object, properties are not reset.