# Alpha does not work in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am continuing an app for iOS directed to iPad. And [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715017/selecting-a-cell-and-changing-the-alpha-of-all-cells-in-tableview-swift) this morning on the site where I got the right answer to my question. But for some reason, the Alpha is not working in cells of my table.

This is my View ties TableView:

[image]

And this is my Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let data:[String] = ["Row 0","Row 1", "Row 2","Row 3","Row 4","Row 5","Row 6"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var rowSelected:Int! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell
        if rowSelected != nil {
            if rowSelected > indexPath.row {
                cell.alpha = 0.7
            } else if rowSelected == indexPath.row {
                cell.alpha = 1.0
            } else {
                cell.alpha = 0.3
            }
        }

        cell.labelText.text = self.data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.rowSelected = indexPath.row

        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}
```

When I select one row, nothing happens, the Alpha does not. In this example, I applied the Alpha directly in cell (I disabled the Opaque option in the cell - the cell is not opaque). **In the original app I have 2 Labels, 2 buttons and a picture. To be more practical, necessary for the Alpha is used directly in the Cell.**

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you expect anything to change when you select a row? The code you posted only updates the selected row and the selected row is setup to have an alpha of 1.0. You should be reloading all visible rows whenever a row is selected.

Comment: @rmaddy What I need to do to change the Alpha of all cell (1.0 / 0.7 / 0.5) when selecting a row?

Comment: Right. Which is why I stated that you need to reload all visible cells when you select a row. You are only reloading the selected cell.

Comment: I'm still searching for the best way to do this. When I select a row, the rows above are with Alpha equal to 0.7, the selected row with Alpha is equal to 1.0, and the rows below are with Alpha equal to 0.5.

Comment: And once again, you need to reload all visible rows when you select a row. That's the best way.

Comment: In tableView (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) changed the loading table by tableView.reloadData(), but nothing happened. Still not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 elements which you need to take care:

1. `UITableView` If your tableview's background is white, whatever the
   alpha you will set on cell, it will not get reflected on `UI`
   properly. try to set tableview's background color to transparent.
2. `UITableViewCell` expecting you are working on this control.
3. `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`  Try to set `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` background color to transparent also.

Comment: UITableViewCell's contentview: Try to set UITableViewCell's contentview background color to transparent also  .. did the trick for me, thanks

Comment: I was referring to your solution that it did the trick for me :D
not like I was suggesting a new solution, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old thread. But I just want to leave my suggestion here if anyone may find it useful. You can apply the `alpha` to the `UITableViewCell`'s content view this works for me.

`cell.contentView.alpha = 0.3`

Answer (score 1):

You probably still have the white background from the `tableView`. Try setting the background of the `tableView` to clear either in code:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
```

or in the Interface editor:

[image]

Comment: I applied the background as you said. And using the print, I found that the Alpha is being applied, but in TableView nothing happens. Something is missing, but still do not know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background on the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell` to clear Color.
On the `ContentView`, set the background color to something other than Default (like white), plus set the alpha there.

If you have a custom cell with a background image and other content, set the `ContentView` to clear, and set your cell's background image to a lower alpha.

Comment: Setting the cell's background color alpha fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` only gets called when the tableview renders the cells the first time. Try reloading the data of the tableview for a quick result.

In the long run, you should refactor the alpha modification to also happen on all visible cells when a selection happens.

Comment: The result is the same. I have not found the solution yet.

Comment: This is not correct. This method is called any time a cell becomes visible.